# MySQL ProgrammingError 1064 with SELECT statement

Tags: python, mysql

```
table = "tbl_" + platform + "_chks"
search = "%" + search + "%"

cur.execute('''SELECT check_id,check_name,%s, FROM %s WHERE %s LIKE %s;''', (field,table,field,search))
```

I'm getting the following error:

> ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''tbl_linux_chks' WHERE 'check_name' LIKE '%test%'' at line 1)

Comment: You can't use parameters in table or field names like this

Comment: is there no alternative? I'd rather not have to make redundant if/elif statements

Comment: You'll have to concatenate the values to the SQL string manually. And you'll have to make sure they're all handled by you so there's no possibility for injection

Comment: I've edited my question with your suggestion (see above), still getting same error

Comment: You can't use %s for table or field names. Put the proper strings there.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
cur.execute("""SELECT check_id,check_name,{} 
               FROM tbl_{}_chks 
               WHERE {} LIKE '%%{}%%'
               """.format(field,platform,field,search))
```

The reason this driver developers separate arguments from query is security. So you should take care about the data in the variables before using this solution.

Comment: Now it gives me TypeError: not enough arguments for format string

Comment: What data is in variables field,platform,field,search? Could it be that they have spec-symbols?

Comment: IT WORKED!  Thank you!

Comment: this is trivially vulnerable against sql injection!

Comment: @mata It depends on the source of variables.

Comment: @AstraSerg Exactly, but your answer doesn't mention that. The OP never said anything about the source of those variables, so you shouldn't treat them as 'safe'. Specially the `search` variable looks as it could very well be user input. It's bad practice to post potentially unsafe code. And answers without explanation and just a code snipplet are generally considered poor quality answers on SO.

Comment: @mata I do care about SO quality answers, so I edited my answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`%s` query parameter placeholders can only be used for that, query parameters, not for identifiers like table or column names. When query parameters are used, strings are automatically quoted and escaped before inserted in a query, but quoting for table and column names is different.

MySQL uses single or double quotes for quoting values, but it uses backticks (`) for quoting identifiers.

For this to work correctly, you need to create the query first (using string formatting), then you can execute that query using query parameters:

```
# `field` and `platform` must not come from user input, or be validated!
table = "tbl_" + platform + "_chks"
query = ('SELECT check_id, check_name, `{0}` FROM `{1}` WHERE `{0}` LIKE %s'
         .format(field, table))
cur.execute(query, ("%" + search + "%",))
```

Make really sure that `platform` and `fields` do not come from user input, otherwise you'll have an sql injection vulnerability.